# Spritekit SKRange Zrotation SKConstraint lower/upper limit minus vs positive Radians

Tags: sprite-kit

I am trying to figure out how I should use SKRange with Zrotation when I need to go over 180 degrees.

This is what I have;

```
    let higherlimit = CGFloat( 170 * 3.14 / 180 )
    let lowerlimit = CGFloat( 0 * 3.14 / 180 )
    let rotationRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: lowerlimit, upperLimit: higherlimit )

    let rotationConstraint = SKConstraint.zRotation(rotationRange)
    wheel.constraints = [rotationConstraint]
```

The above works great, I cannot turn the wheel over 170 degrees. However when I try to the following;

```
    let higherlimit = CGFloat( -90 * 3.14 / 180 )
    let lowerlimit = CGFloat( 0 * 3.14 / 180 )
    let rotationRange = SKRange(lowerLimit: lowerlimit, upperLimit: higherlimit )

    let rotationConstraint = SKConstraint.zRotation(rotationRange)
    wheel.constraints = [rotationConstraint]
```

The above doesn't work, it will lock the wheel in a certain angle. I am aware about positive and negative radians but I cannot figure out how to accomplish the above.

Thanks very much in advance,
w//

Comment: your lower and higher are backwards.... you should be going from -180 to posititve 179 (or whatever your range is)

Comment: Here an example of working SKRange :) https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/Compass/Compass/GameScene.swift

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded doing this by adding an extension;

depending on your 'flavour' ..

```
extension CGFloat {
    var toDegreesNormalizedNegative : CGFloat {
        let rad = -self
        let deg = rad * 180 / .pi
        return CGFloat(Int ( deg >= 0 ? deg : deg + 360 ))
    }
}


extension CGFloat {
    var toDegreesNormalized : CGFloat {
        let deg = self * 180 / .pi
        return CGFloat(Int ( deg >= 0 ? deg : deg + 360 ))
    }
}
```

then simply check in update(_ .. or touchesBegan or etc that it wont go over the required limit(s)